# Pass data from java to jsp

Tags: java, rest, jsp

I am having troubles accessing my java class in jsp.

In jsp:

```
 <%@ page import="package.ClientWithResponseHandler" %> 
 <% ClientWithResponseHandler jira = new ClientWithResponseHandler();
 System.out.println(jira.getJIRA()); %>
```

In java:

```
public class ClientWithResponseHandler {

 public String getJIRA() throws Exception {
    String string="";
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("someURL");

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String[] responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler).replace("[", "").replace("}]","").split("},");
        for (int i=0;i<responseBody.length;i++)
        {
            responseBody[i]+="}";
           JSONObject project= new JSONObject(responseBody[i]);         
   string +=project.getString("name");
   string+="||";
            String url=project.getString("self");
            HttpGet httpget2 = new HttpGet(url);

            String responseBody2 = httpclient.execute(httpget2, responseHandler);
                JSONObject taskall= new JSONObject(responseBody2);
                   JSONArray tasks=taskall.getJSONArray("components");
                   for(int j=0;j<tasks.length();j++)
                   {
                       JSONObject task= tasks.getJSONObject(j);
                           string+=task.getString("name");
                           string+="|";
                   }
        }
    return string;
          }
    }
```

By calling the method, getJIRA(), I want it to return a string of data that I got my making a rest call.  I have checked it and I think the java class does work properly and returns a string.  When i run my jsp page, an exception is thrown:

```
HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 23
23: <% ClientWithResponseHandler jira = new ClientWithResponseHandler();

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/ResponseHandler
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/ResponseHandler
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler
```

I am fairly new to programming, so I have no idea what any of that means.  If anyone could help me out, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: it seems that you servlet-container can't find your libraries

Comment: the import in your jsp looks incorrect - package is a keyword. import takes a fully qualified classname but shouldn't include package.

Comment: @user2264997 in my code it does not say package.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your Apache HTTP Client JAR is not in you web application classpath. Try to check if its inside your `WEB-INF/lib` folder inside you WAR file.